# How to get div id from html file into comoponent in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I am beginner for Angular2.I have index.html file, inside index file i have div element, I want to get this div's id inside component(.ts).

Please help me, Thnaks.

Comment: What do you need it for ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a component and then place the "div" tag inside the template of the component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: '<div [id]="divid'></div>'
})
export class SomeComponent {
    divid: number;
}
```

The brackets around the "id" in your div essentially say pull this value from my component.

Then, in your index.html file, place the tag name of your component

```
<some-component></some-component>
```